# Excel Power Query storing the old data in a column

Tags: powerquery

In excel power query I have a linked excel file where only the last column is updated by the team. For example is the cut-off data day is Jan 13th then the data is titled Jan 13 and the rows are updated for this week. When the update is done the following week, the column header is changed to Jan 20. How can I keep the old data for Jan 13th in power query so that I only get the new data in a new column when refreshed?

I tried but I am stuck

Comment: you have not provided enough info to help you. What does the data look like? What do you want it to look like?

Comment: I just found this on youtube. Curbal is an amazing person, and she has solved this exact problem. I will post the link in case someone has the same issue. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yBJr0sAc-m4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerQuery doesn't store any data, it's essentially a transformation script, that uses whatever is in the linked source when refreshed. So if the data for 13th is gone at the source it will be gone in PowerQuery too. If the column for 20th is added next to column for 13th, then you can create a dynamic logic that would keep more columns.

You could create a logic preserving the historical data using VBA (to store it in the not linked table), but in Excel & M it is not possible. With PowerBI there is an option of incremental refresh that potentially could be used here, but it's not available in Excel